# How to pass the string values to Asynchronous task in seperate calss in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created a separate class for Asynchronous task. How can I pass the string value to that Asynchronous task class? Please refer my code below.

**In Main class to call Asynchronous task class**

```
 String product_id,av_quantity;
 Stock_updatetask = new Stock_update();
 Stock_updatetask.execute(product_id,av_quantity);
```

How to send String product_id,av_quantity values to Asynchronous task Class

**Asynchronous task Class**

```
public class Stock_update extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

JSONArray jsonarray;


protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        // checkInternetConnection();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),20000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 20000);

        HttpResponse response;


        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.name.in/cakefoodnew/customer/stockUpdate?json=");

        /*json.put("submenu_id", "" + product_id);
        json.put("available_quantity", "" + av_quantity);*/
        // Log.v("id", ""+json);

        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);

        if (response != null) {
            // get a data
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String a = convertStreamToString(in);
            // Log.v("id", ""+a);

            try {

                jsonarray = new JSONArray("[" + a + "]");
                json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
                //stock_update = (json.getString("Success"));

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}

// Json response
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: use the constructor to pass values to asynctak. pass the values when u call the asynctask constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get  product_id,av_quantity values inside  `doInBackground` method as :

```
    //....your code here...
   json.put("submenu_id", "" + params[0]); //<<<< get product_id
   json.put("available_quantity", "" + params[1]); //<<< get av_quantity
    // Log.v("id", ""+json);

    post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
```

because `doInBackground` method parameter  is `Varargs` you can get more about Varargs here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

or second way is you can pass both values by creating an `Stock_update` constructor as :

```
public class Stock_update extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 String product_id,av_quantity;
public Stock_update(String product_id,String av_quantity){

   this.product_id=product_id;
   this.av_quantity=av_quantity;
 }
//your code here
}
```

pass both values at time of object creation of Stock_update class :

```
Stock_updatetask = new Stock_update(product_id,av_quantity);
```

now you are able to use `product_id,av_quantity` in whole `Stock_update` class including `doInBackground`

Comment: how to return the values to main class from Asynchronous task Class.

Comment: @Yugesh : you will need to call get method of AsyncTask to get back value in caller Activity but this will freeze main ui thread until AsyncTask execution is not complete. and second way is put your UI related code inside onPostExecute to update

Comment: post Execute is not possible in my application i think,because my button is in customized list view.how to use get method of AsyncTask.

Comment: @Yugesh : i think this is not related to current question. best way is just make an new question regarding new issue to get quick help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this code

```
DownloadingProgressTask downloadingProgressTask = new DownloadingProgressTask(
                                    Utilities.arrayRSSDownload.get(0).getUrl(),
                                    mainprogressbar, Utilities.arrayRSSDownload
                                            .get(0).getTitle());
                            downloadingProgressTask.execute();
```

And then in class

```
private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    String fileName;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    public DownloadingProgressTask(String url1, ProgressBar progress,
            String filetitle) {

        urllink = url1;
        fileName = filetitle;
        progressbar = progress;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        mainprogressbar.setProgress(0);
        progressbar.setProgress(0);

        myDatabase.updateDownloadStatus(fileName, 2);
        // Updating the home screen list
        setListData();
    }

       --- rest of code
```

Comment: but this is not related to current problem, Nirali?